# Discrete Taylor's Formula in n dimensions

Tags: taylor-series

I am searching for discrete form of Taylor's formula in n dimensions. Please share the appropriate resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the discrete Taylor´s formula for dimensions $1$ and $2$ in pages 28 and 914 respectively of the book *Difference equations and inequalities* by Ravi P. Agarwal. I guess other books in difference equations might contain formulas for higher dimensions.

Comment: May I ask you what is the necessary background knowledge to work through Agarwal's book?

Comment: @Dal: It is hard to tell, it is a huge book with a lot of material. But I´d say you can start and go through a big chunk of it just with a Calculus and a Linear Algebra course.

Comment: I see. Thank you.